What is the terminology for this type of "dual" graph?
Let $G = (V, E)$ be a directed graph and $\phi: E\times E\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ such that for all $(v_1, v_2),(v_3, v_4)\in \phi^{-1}(1)$ we have $v_2=v_3$. Let $G^{\phi} = (E, \phi^{-1}(1))$.
Is there an accepted term for this object $G^{\phi}$?
In plain English, this is a type of "dual" graph whose vertices are the edges of the original graph, and two edges are connected if they share the middle edge and an additional condition $\phi$ holds true. For example, if $G$ describes a network of roads (edges) connecting intersections (vertices), $G^{\phi}$ could be used to represent possible turns.

Is this a subgraph of the line graph?
